# PDF viewer in online(Internet conectivity) as well as offline mode

Tags: android

The PDF content can be of online as well as offline mode, I need to show pdf in my own customized layout so, Intent can't be used. Any suggestion will be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of there is no support for pdf in Android so you need to open in some other app like adob or if you want to do it right way then need make the load lib like vudroid and apdfviewer .

apdfviewer is very good but there is no support how to compile source code, actually all lib work with c++ in backend so you need to install the ndk.

Vudroid is slow but you can compile easily.

I hope this will help you.

But
Some phones (like the Nexus One) come with a version of Quickoffice pre-installed so it may be as easy as sending the appropriate Intent once you've saved the file to the SD card.

```
 public class OpenPdf extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OpenPdfButton);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    File file = new File("/sdcard/example.pdf");

                    if (file.exists()) {
                        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                        try {
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } 
                        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(OpenPdf.this, 
                                "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I cannot use the intent because I need the customized layout, when the intent start we cannot control over it.

Comment: As its opening a file You cannot do anything with it

Comment: Also, you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there). It will help you get more answers.

Comment: Any more idea regarding building own PDF viewer or somethings like that.

Answer (score 5):

Yes we are able to show pdf content onLine with the help of google doc api Here i am given code for using it. **for ON Line Mode**

```
public class ReaderActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   WebView webView=(WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.WebView01);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eli.sdsu.edu%2Fcourses%2Ffall09%2Fcs696%2Fnotes%2FAndroid13Web.pdf");
        //intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=---------Your URL");

       }}
```

for OFF Line Mode

```
        File file = new File(mRealPath);
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setDataAndType(path, getString(R.string.application_type));
        try 
        {
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(FirstTab.this, 
                getString(R.string.no_application_found), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Note-:In off line mode first you have download file form server to own local device in sd-card the get path of this document and put it on in the place of path variable then you get answer of your hole question.

In this code you should use your url in the place my url.
I hope this is help.

Comment: so, what will be the case in the offline mode ?

Comment: I have edited my last answer add how to read pdf in offline mode

Comment: Thank's for your response.. let me try.

Comment: can I control the Activity as the adobe reader open the pdf file, now I want it to disable certain functionality provided by Adobe reader (Eg. denied for copy the content)

Answer (score 1):

I found that Internet connectivity mode :- through google doc we can open the pdf.
but in the Internet offline mode:- we need to use Intent and open the pdf file through any one of the pdf viewer application install in the device.

one things we can do in the offline mode is that, instead of opening the option of multiple pdf viewer reader in device and select one application to open pdf file we can open the pdf with the particular application.